# SEDE query for questions that are only quote & code?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Is it possible to query on https://data.stackexchange.com/ the questions that are made purely of:

- quoted content (starts with `\n>...`) and stops at a blank line `\n\n`)
- indented code (starts with `\n    ...`) and stops at a new line `\n`)

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46110431/1

<sub>Bonus support:</sub>

<sub>* simple escaped code (starts with `` `... `` and stops with `` ` ``)</sub>

Comment: So you need to check for posts where all lines start with spaces or `>`. Not sure how you'd do that in SEDE, though...

Comment: @Cerbrus, no, it's more complex: quoted content allows lines starting by anything; it only stops at a blank line. But a simplified query would be a start.

Comment: Oh, right... Ehm, good luck writing a query :D

Comment: You could adapt my query that sorts questions on Anime.SE by spoiler % here: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/714557/questions-on-anime-se-sorted-by-spoiler

Comment: I believe this could be achieved pretty easily by searching for the reverse (posts not containing any lines not starting with a letter or 4 spaces). I'll give it a try.

Comment: How about this: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/820238 it is not easy to find multiple blocks that satisfy the criteria

Comment: Do you have a general reason for searching for such posts? I'm assuming you're looking for poorly asked questions with that criteria? Perhaps with an explanation of what you're trying to do you'll get more useful queries as opposed to a single all inclusive query.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [the following](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/820245/only-quotes-and-code) somewhat dirty solution. Parsing HTML with SQL is not a good plan, but I did it anyway.

It returns all questions not containing any normal text (paragraphs or headings), except for the first paragraph inside a blockquote.

Edit: after some more testing, it doesn't perform that well. It also identifies quote-only questions, and code-only questions that have an old-style duplicate mark. It also identifies quote + image-only answers, but that image is often code.

Comment: Thank you. Your query seems to show that there is 4-5 questions like this daily.

Answer (score 2):

If question quality is something you're looking at, this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/820400/questions-that-are-only-code) is pretty good on it's own:

```
SELECT TOP 50 Id AS [Post Link],body
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.Body NOT LIKE '%<p>%'
AND PostTypeId = 1
AND creationdate > '2018-03-01'
```

Shows posts that do not contain any paragraph tags `<p>`, which shows [code only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076205/how-to-go-about-fixing-apt) questions as well as [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078280/when-to-use-a-fragment-over-an-activity) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065655/spark-streaming-javanetworkwordcount-example-error) that are using the text editor poorly, with bullet lists and headers, but no paragraphs.

It excludes questions with block quotes, which come looking like below:

```
<blockquote> <p>....</p> </blockquote>
```

and includes `char(10)` + `char(13)` combos as [Erik has tried to work around](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364544/57475). Had a quick attempt at trying to include them, but couldn't get it working with the above filter.

Comment: Thank you. Your query seems to show that there is 4-5 questions like this daily.